# Вызов метода родительского компонента Vue

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть вложенный дочерний компонент:

```
<template>
    <main>
        ...
        <feedback></feedback>
    </main>
</template>
```

В основном компоненте у меня есть метод:

```
methods: {
    filledInput: function () {
        ...
    }
},
```

Как вызвать это метод  в дочернем компоненте `feedback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно дать сигнал (событие) из компонента feedback компоненту-родителю через `$emit('my-event')`, а он в свою очередь может случать это событие через `@my-event="filledInput"`.

```js
var feedback = {
  template: `<button @click="$emit('my-event')">
    Вызвать родительский filledInput 
  </button>`
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { feedback },
  methods: {
    filledInput () {
      console.log('filledInput вызвался')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <feedback @my-event="filledInput">
  </feedback>

</div>
```

Comment: Оо
спасибо! 
А если у меня вложенность будет больше?

Comment: @SkipTyler думаю тут подойдет vuex, можно вызвать action. Конечно есть и другие способы, как по мне это самый удобный и правильный.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!